# Porqué Laravel borra las variables URL después del signo de interrogación?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, routes

En Laravel 8 tengo el siguiente link:

```
<a href="mysite.test/var1?var2=2&var3=3">link</a>
```

El problema que tengo es que al dirigirme a dicho link, todas las variables posteriores al signo de interrogación se borran y no son recibidas en el controlador.
El link redirige a:

```
mysite.test/var1
```

Alguien sabe como solucionar este problema?
Gracias.

Comment: En la url que muestra el navegador, es intencional que no aparezcan las query strings, ya que laravel usa ["urls amigables"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls). Pero en el método correspondiente del controlador, ¿si haces `request()->query('var2');` no te devuelve el valor de la query string?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ, el controlador me devuelve null.
Incluso usando los dos métodos:

public function form1(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->query('utm_id');
        $id = request()->query('utm_id');
        dd($id);

        return view('form1');
    }

Ninguna de las dos formas me devuelve el valor enviado.

Comment: A mí sí me funciona https://phpsandbox.io/n/floral-hall-vepv-m1t36?files=%2Froutes%2Fweb.php . Estarás haciendo otra cosa que no muestras en la pregunta

Comment: O tal vez ese `href="mysite.test...`", podrías reemplazarlo por un herlper de laravel como `url()` o `route()` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls y probar que llegue al controlador. También las herramientas para desarrollo del navegador para ver que request envía, para compararlo con el quest de laravel